# Accessing Scala nested classes from Java

Tags: java, scala

Let's say we have the following class structure in Scala.

```
object Foo {
  class Bar
}
```

We can easily construct `Bar` in Java with `new Foo.Bar()`. But everything changes when we add an extra level of nested classes.

```
object Foo {
  object Bar {
    class Baz
  }
}
```

Somehow, it's no longer possible to construct the most inner class `Baz` in Java. Looking at the `javap` output, I can't see any significant difference between first (2 levels) and second cases (3 levels). Generated code looks pretty reasonable to me.

2 levels:

```
public class Foo$Bar { ... }
```

3 levels

```
public class Foo$Bar$Baz { ... }
```

With that said, what's the difference between 2-level vs. 3-level nested Scala classes when they accessed from Java?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's give the two versions different names to make them a little easier to talk about:

```
object Foo1 {
  class Bar1
}

object Foo2 {
  object Bar2 {
    class Baz2
  }
}
```

Now if you look at the class files, you'll see that the Scala compiler has created a `Foo1` class. When you run `javap -v` on `Foo1$Bar1`, you'll see that that class is listed as the enclosing class:

```
InnerClasses:
     public static #14= #2 of #13; //Bar1=class Foo1$Bar1 of class Foo1
```

This is exactly what would happen with a static nested class in Java, so the Java compiler is perfectly happy to compile `new Foo1.Bar1()` for you.

Now look at the `javap -v` output for `Foo2$Bar2$Baz2`:

```
InnerClasses:
     public static #16= #13 of #15; //Bar2$=class Foo2$Bar2$ of class Foo2
     public static #17= #2 of #13; //Baz2=class Foo2$Bar2$Baz2 of class Foo2$Bar2$
```

Now the enclosing class is `Foo2$Bar2$`, not `Foo2$Bar2` (in fact the Scala compiler doesn't even generate a `Foo2$Bar2` unless you add a companion class for `object Bar2`). The Java compiler expects a static inner class `Baz2` of a enclosing class `Foo2$Bar2$` to be named `Foo2$Bar2$$Baz2`, with two dollar signs. This doesn't match what it's actually got (`Foo2$Bar2$Baz2`), so it says no to `new Foo2.Bar2.Baz2()`.

Java is perfectly happy to accept dollar signs in class names, and in this case since it can't figure out how to interpret `Foo2$Bar2$Baz2` as an inner class of some kind, it'll let you create an instance with `new Foo2$Bar2$Baz2()`. So that's a workaround, just not a very pretty one.

Why does the Scala compiler treat `Foo1` and `Bar2` differently (in the sense that `Bar2` doesn't get a `Bar2` class), and why does the enclosing class listed in the `InnerClasses` attribute for `Baz2` have a dollar sign on the end, while the one for `Bar1` doesn't? I don't really have any idea. But that's the difference—you just need a little more verbosity to see it with `javap`.