# JAVA - Instantiate Scala case class

Tags: java, scala, class, case-class, scala-java-interop

after few days of search, I need your help to solve my problem.

I have a java program and I want to call a library written in scala, the jar is in classpath.

Scala main class:

```
object Program{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    ...
  }

  case class Config(param1, param2) {

    def parseProgramFromFiles(){}
    ...

  }

}
```

I'm trying to instantiate **Config** using

```
Program.Config config = new Program.Config(param1, param2);
```

I got this error: java: package **Program** does not exist

Program is in default package

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala uses [name mangling](https://github.com/non/sbt-javap#name-mangling) to encode various Scala types into Java namespaces

> Scala types are often found inside of object values as a form of
>   namespacing. Scala uses a $ delimiter to mangle these names. For
>   example, given `object Kennel { class Dog }` the inner class name would
>   become `Kennel$Dog`.

Hence try

```
new Program$Config("foo", "bar");
```

---

EDIT: Hmm...actually it seems `new Program.Config("foo", "bar")` [should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30810426/5205022) as

```
javap -v Program$Config.class
```

gives

```
InnerClasses:
     public static #11= #10 of #2; //Config=class Program$Config of class Program
     public static #14= #13 of #2; //Config$=class Program$Config$ of class Program
```

and indeed on my machine given

```
package example

object Program {
  case class Config(param1: String, param2: String)
}
```

then

```
package example;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Program.Config config = new Program.Config("foo", "bar");
        System.out.println(config);
    }
}
```

outputs `Config(foo,bar)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Intellij cannot resolve symbol Program$Config

Comment: Note that, typically in Scala, you would not construct an instance of a case class via the case class' constructor but rather by calling the companion object's `apply` method. In Java, that would look roughly like `Program.Config$.apply(bla)`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag `Program.Config$.MODULE$.apply("foo", "bar")` seems to work.

Comment: I was able to instantiate the case class **Config** by updating the library and adding the package under name example for object **Program** and using ```Program.Config config = new Program.Config("foo", "bar");```

Thank you for useful response.